# ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Right now, I am working with cosmwasm and trying to deploy the [cw-plus smart contracts](https://github.com/CosmWasm/cw-plus/tree/main/contracts).

I was able to run the cargo cli `cargo build-bpf` but couldn't deploy it by using cli `solana program deploy <the path of so file>`.
I encountered this issue:

```
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Multiple or no text sections,
consider removing llc option: -function-sections
```